# SQL- How to add in named columns directly corresponding to an ID when join doesn't cover them

Tags: sql, join, presto

I'm trying to join two tables based on the date, ID and country. Table 1 has an extra column that corresponds directly to the ID column
table 1

```
| Date      | ID      |Country|ID name                 |Clicks
| ----------| --------|-------|------------------------|------- |
| 25/02/2021| 42587750|Spain  |Targeting Details Spain |5
| 26/02/2021| 42587750|Spain  |Targeting Details Spain |15
```

However, the other table tracks countries slightly differently, so it looks like this

```
Table 2
| Date      | ID      |Country|Clicks
| ----------| --------|-------|------|
| 25/02/2021| 42587750|Spain  |4
| 25/02/2021| 42587750|France |1
| 26/02/2021| 42587750|Spain  |13
| 26/02/2021| 42587750|Italy  |2
```

I want to see all cases of the countries, so I currently have done a full join based on date, ID and country. However, this is producing data like this

| Date | table1.ID | table1.Country | table2.ID | table2.Country | ID name | table1.Clicks | table2.clicks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25/02/2021 | 42587750 | Spain | 42587750 | Spain | Targeting Details Spain | 5 | 4 |
| 26/02/2021 | 42587750 | Spain | 42587750 | Spain | Targeting Details Spain | 15 | 13 |
| 25/02/2021 |  |  | 42587750 | France |  |  | 1 |
| 25/02/2021 |  |  | 42587750 | Italy |  |  | 1 |

I used this for the join:

```
from table1 full outer join table2 on table1.date=table2.date and table1.ID=table2.ID and table1.country=table2.country
```

Where I have all the correct details coming in for when all 3 things I'm joining on matches, but when the country is different, I don't have the ID name coming through anymore.

Is it possible to have the ID name be pulled through even when the country is not matching, while pulling  in the country?

I can get the correct numbers when I take out the country level information, like this

```
from table1 full outer join table2 on table1.date=table2.date and table1.ID=table2.ID
```

I've tried using the AVG function instead of SUM for the clicks, but that hasn't worked.

Comment: thank you @ankit for fixing the formatting!

Comment: What ID name value you are expecting for different country and where is that stored?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results to illustrate what you want to do.

Comment: Hi @AnkitBajpai, I was expecting the ID name to match the IDs. So this case I would expect all 42587750 IDs to have Targeting Details Spain as the ID name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your query structured using `coalesce()`?

```
select coalesce(t1.date, t2.date) as date,
       coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) as id,
       coalesce(t1.country, t2.country),
       coalesce(t1.idname, max(t1.idname) over (partition by coalesce(t1.id, t2.id)) as idname,
       t1.clicks, t2.clicks
from table1 t1 full outer join
     table2 t2
     on t1.date = t2.date and 
        t1.ID = t2.ID and
        t1.country = t2.country
```

Comment: The server is registering this bit ["max"(aggregate.line_item_id) OVER (PARTITION BY COALESCE(aggregate.line_item_id, dbm.line_item_id))] as an aggregation, window function or a grouping funciton, and is complaining about having that inside the group by function

Comment: @Aki . . . That doesn't make sense.  That is a window function and Presto should handle that just fine.  There are no aggregation functions in the query, so I suspect the query you are running is different from this.

Comment: probably something about me not putting the right parenthesis in the right place. thank you @gordon for this though, i'll just play around with the line

Comment: @Aki . . . I can demonstrate that it works using other databases, but I don't know of a "fiddle" for Presto online.